# Python csv conversion to specific nested json

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe (csv file loaded into Pandas) as below :

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    name    amount
1       USA     4000    Air     60  Education   200
1       USA     4000    Air     60  Car         100
1       USA     4000    Air     60  Restaurant  100
2       UK      5000    Cash    50  Government  125
2       UK      5000    Cash    50  Restaurant  135
```

Now, i need to convert it into nested json format. For one record ( Col1, col2, col3, col4 - consider for grouping )

Below Json format is expected output :

```
{
 “col5”: 60,
 “col4”: [
   {
     “name”: “Air”
   }
 ],
 “expenses”: [
   {
     “amount”: 200,
     “name”: “Education”
   },
   {
     “amount”: Car,
     “name”: “Car”
   },
   {
     “amount”: 100,
     “name”: “Restaurant”
   }
 ],
 “col1”: 1,
 “col2”: “USA”,
 “col3”: “4000”
}
```

I understand, its going to be bit complex code... But is there some one to help ?
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

For dictionary:

```
d = (df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'])
       .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['name'], x['amount'])))
       .reset_index(name='expenses')
       .to_dict(orient='records')
       )
print (d)
```

For json:

```
j = (df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'])
       .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['name'], x['amount'])))
       .reset_index(name='expenses')
       .to_json(orient='records')
       )
print (j)
```